# How to import Google Contacts into a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-contacts-api

seems like this should be VERY simple....but it's not. I tried using omincontacts, which was easy but doesn't return contact's phone numbers! Which is the only thing I really need.

Is there a way to get omnicontacts working with phone numbers?

Is there another "rails way" of importing gmail contacts?

I also tried using their gem here: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client

Thanks!